# Match the two letter country code to predefined array of country code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, geolocation

I am trying to get the country code of the user's current location using Javascript. With the code, I have, I will be getting two letter country code and then I need to match that two letter country code with my predefined array to get the three letter country code.

Below is my code, but it is not working as soon as I added my predefined array things for three letter country code. none of my alert box are working now.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Get web visitor's location</title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>

    var threeLtrCC.US = 'USA';
    var threeLtrCC.IN = 'IND';

$(document).ready( function() {

    $.getJSON( "http://smart-ip.net/geoip-json?callback=?",
        function(data){
            alert( data.countryCode);
            var cc = threeLtrCC[data.countryCode];
            var countryCode=data.countryCode

            alert(cc);
            $('#newURL').attr('href','https://www.google.com&jobid='+countryCode);
        }
    );
}); 

    </script>

    </head>
    <body>
<hr/>

<a id="newURL">url</a>

    </body>
</html>
```

It is not alerting me anything. Suppose if the country code is US, then it should get matched with my predefined array and print it out as USA.

What wrong I am doing?

Comment: Please look in the [JavaScript error console](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and tell what errors you see there and which lines they point to.

Comment: Shouldn't you declare threLtrCC before assigning its array values? Like var threLtrCC = {}, threLtrCC.US = 'USA';

Comment: any errors u are getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be declaring two variables with this line:

```
var threeLtrCC.US = 'USA';
var threeLtrCC.IN = 'IND';
```

Not adding anything to an object of name `threeLtrCC`. You have to declare `threeLtrCC` and then:

```
var threeLtrCC = {}
threeLtrCC.US = 'USA';
threeLtrCC.IN = 'IND';
```

or even

```
var threeLtrCC = {"US": 'USA', "IN" : 'IND'}
```

Demo : http://jsbin.com/ucifup/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

this is wrong

```
var threeLtrCC.US = 'USA';
var threeLtrCC.IN = 'IND';
```

you cannot declare a property of an object

```
var threeLtrCC={IN:"IND",US:"USA"};
```